# form macros in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have app\Services\Macros.php

```
<?php namespace App\Services;

use Collective\Html\FormBuilder;

class Macros extends FormBuilder {

    public function selectBg($name,$selected = '2', $options = array())
    {
        $list = [
            '' => 'Select One...',
            '1' => 'O+ve',
            '2' => 'O-ve',
            '3' => 'A+ve',
            '4' => 'A-ve',
        ];

        return $this->select($name, $list, $selected, $options);
    }

}
```

MacroServiceProvider.php includes the following code:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\Macros;
use Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class MacroServiceProvider
 * @package App\Providers
 */
class MacroServiceProvider extends HtmlServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        parent::register();
        $this->app->singleton('form', function ($app) {
            $form = new Macros($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['view'], $app['session.store']->token());
            return $form->setSessionStore($app['session.store']);
        });
    }

}
```

In the form I called it by using `{{Form::select()}}` but I am getting an error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function Collective\Html\FormBuilder::select(), 0 passed in E:\xamp\htdocs\crud\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 221 and at least 1 expected (View: E:\xamp\htdocs\crud\resources\views\newfile\forms.blade.php)

Comment: Just to be sure, have you added the service provider and facades to your app.php config file?

Comment: Please show us your view too (forms.blade.php)

Comment: Can you clarify if the answer helped you? [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet, I see you have the method called `selectBg`. In order for this to work you have to call it by using `{{ Form::selectBg() }}` instead of `{{ Form::select() }}`.

Since you use parameters, you have to provide at least the `$name` parameter so it becomes

```
{{ Form::selectBg('the name for the $name parameter') }}
```

If you have more parameters (which you do: a string, a number and an array), add them accordingly, for example:

```
{{ Form::selectBg('the name', 2, ['foo', 'bar']) }}
```